# how to get the scorm basic report from moodle

Tags: php, moodle, scorm

I have developed one application in **php.ini** used moodle sessions.so now my problem is I am trying to display the score basic reports of the course in my custom application..after user enrolled for the course those details are showed in a report(tab) page.

I want to get that username, email, and attempts, start date, end date values and showed in my system..is there any way to do this.
I have been tried from past 3 days..I didn't get any solution to do this.

can anyone explain me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scorm only works with javascript, when the scorm file calls `window.API.LMSSetValue(key, value)` is when you will receive the scorm data, because you are the one that implemented and provided the file with that function, you can then store this in the database and fetch it from the database using PHP.

You can't get the email from the SCORM because the [SCORM 1.2 datamodel](https://scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/run-time/run-time-reference/) does not support it.